# What is the correct way to build a thread-safe, multiplatform C library?

Tags: c, gcc, thread-safety, pthreads

Consider the following trivial C program,

```
#include <errno.h>
int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return errno;
}
```

When compiled on Solaris, the behavior of this code is dependent on the presence of `-D_REENTRANT`.

```
solaris$ cc -E test.c | grep return
  return errno;
solaris$ cc -D_REENTRANT -E test.c | grep return
  return  ( * ( ___errno ( ) ) );
```

with the latter version being thread-safe. If we compile the same code on Linux, we get the same behavior independent of `-D_REENTRANT`

```
linux$ gcc -E test.c | grep return
  return (*__errno_location ());
linux$ gcc -D_REENTRANT -E test.c | grep return
  return (*__errno_location ());
```

Solaris' `cc` has the option `-mt`, which implies `-D_REENTRANT`, as does `gcc`'s `-pthread`. However, for a library, specifying these multi-threaded options seems poor, as it injects an unnecessary dependency on the threading runtime. However, if the library needs to be thread-safe (including errno), then the thread-safe semantics are needed at both compile time of the library and of the deriving code. On Linux, this is easy, because errno is always thread-local, but that's not guaranteed on other systems as just demonstrated.

That results in the question: how is a thread-safe library properly compiled and distributed with headers? One option would be to `#define _REENTRANT` in the main header, but this would cause issues if `#include <errno.h>` occurs before the library header inclusion. Another option is to compile the library with `-D_REENTRANT`, and have the main header `#error` if `_REENTRANT` is not defined.

What's the correct/best way to make a thread-safe library and ensure it correctly inter-operates with the code it is linked with?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to any Solaris machine at the moment, so I can't test this. But what happens when you put `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L` as the very first line in `test.c` (before inclusion of `<errno.h>`)? If your Solaris is POSIX-compliant, then that should make `errno` expand to the thread-safe version. This is because POSIX defines `errno` as below:

> For each thread of a process, the value of *errno* shall not be affected by function calls or assignments to *errno* by other threads.

Accordingly, this is portable to any POSIX-compliant system. In fact, if you want to write POSIX-compliant application code, then you should *always* define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to the value appropriate for the minimum version of POSIX you are targeting. The definition should be at the top of every source file before including any headers. From the 2001 version of the standard:

> A Strictly Conforming POSIX Application is an application that requires only the facilities described in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001. Such an application:
>
> ...
>
> 8. For the C programming language, shall define _POSIX_C_SOURCE to be 200112L before any header is included

Comment: `cc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -E test.c | grep return -->  return  ( * ( ___errno ( ) ) );`

Indeed, that works as expected; are you also recommending defining this in the header of the POSIX-compatible library?

Comment: @AlexanderChernyakhovsky: No, it never needs to be defined in any header file. It should always be defined at the top of source files. That is the only way to be sure it is defined before inclusion of any headers. You can also define it on the command line, like you did in your example. That is acceptable. I prefer to see it in the source file, but that's partly just a matter of taste.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like you're advocating for still checking for a  `#define` in my library header, because I still don't want an end-developer to end up getting the wrong errno.

Comment: @AlexanderChernyakhovsky: I don't think it's worth worrying about the end-developer using the wrong errno. Just ensure your library is POSIX-compliant. If the end user has trouble because they aren't being POSIX-compliant, then let them solve the problem. There isn't a "correct" or portable way to accomodate incorrect, non-portable programs :)  Heck, it may even just work for them. There is nothing preventing the implementation from having `__errno_location()` return the location of the single statically allocated `errno` when the program is single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

If your library uses autoconf, you probably want to use the [AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Posix-Variants.html) macro. That macro sets some target-specific defines which enable POSIX +extensions semantics. I don't have a Solaris system to test on at the moment, but I believe _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS should enable the thread-safe errno. At least it enables the POSIX _r() functions rather than the POSIX-draft _r() variants which Solaris annoyingly provides by default.